# how to call a class in "vendor" directory from a class in "webroot" directory - Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, rollbar

i'm new in cakephp, i want to use some methods (implemented in a class existing in vendor directory, i get it with composer) in an extern class (existing in webroot directory).

I tried to use :

```
use Rollbar\Rollbar;
//some code  
Rollbar::init($config) //line 23
```

but it show me the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Rollbar\Rollbar' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectX\webroot\classX.php:23.
```

Any help please ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

include library file using

```
 require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . "my_library_folder" . DS . "my_library_base_class.php")
```

this includes the library code file in your code.

Comment: It show me 2 errors: 1 /PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectX\webroot\classX.php on line 6 . 2/Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectX\webroot\classX.php on line 6

Comment: i think your code work just if we use it in controller or model class , not in an extern class in webroot ?